# Need help regarding HIbernate count query

Tags: java, hibernate

We have a use case to count no. of rows returned by actual query. I am not getting how can I get it using criteria in hibernate. 
For example suppose I want to run query

```
select sum(TOTAL_EARNINGS) from table where column1 = 'value1' group by column2);
```

Along with this query result I also want to get total rows return by above query(above query may have rownum limit also but for total rows I have to ignore rownum limit).

```
select count(*) from (select sum(TOTAL_EARNINGS) from table
                where column1 = 'value1' group by column2);
```

Is there any easy way of getting this data. I am fine with running separate query to get count data but I am not getting how can I write this in hibernate using criteria. I can't even see any option in SubQueries which I can use

Comment: Particular reasons why you can't count the rows from java side? Or use HQL?

Answer (score 0):

In general with criteria you can use projections.
You can do so, if you have an entity "Your" mapped by Hibernate:

**Edited**:
Accordingly to your comment, you need two results, a total count and a group by results.

```
//the group by results...
List result1 = session.createCriteria("Your.class").setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
            .add(Projections.groupProperty("column2"))
            .add(Projections.sum("totalErnings"))
    ).list();

//the total count result
return (Integer) session.createCriteria("Your.class").add(Restrictions.eq("column1", val)).setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult();
```

Comment: My query also has a group by condition. So if I add groupBy column2 in your code then I will get result of count(*) at column2 values level. But I want total result count

Comment: Hi Raul, I suggest you to do this in two steps... I will change my code accordingly

Comment: Query 2 will not generate correct result I want. Basically I want no of rows after applying group by. No of rows with group by criteria and without group by criteria are different

Comment: Uhm sorry I don't get it... so you want the number of groups? Can't you so just do list1.size() ? So you can use also the returned values?

Comment: For most of my query I will use pagination so I want to run 2 separate query 1 to get count and second to select paginated result. I will use same where and group by clause in both queries

Comment: I am still not able to find solution for this. Can some please help me figuring out this